# Python requests: Handle HTTP Status 'Pending'

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download a CSV file from a server. The problem is, that it takes up to three minutes until the server responds with the (large) CSV file.

Simple exmaple:

```
Send POST request to some_url/export
Request is pending
After three minutes the server responds with the generated data.
```

Requests just keeps blocking forever and will never return anything.

```py
"""
My code
"""

 def export_customers(self) -> Optional[r.Response]:
        session = r.Session()
        url = self.base_url + '/export.php'
        headers = {
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'iframe',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
            'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1'
        }
        data = {} # omitted
        response = session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
        return response
```

Comment: Add a timeout https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.8.1/user/advanced/#timeouts

Comment: Didnt help. I already tried it. :-/

Comment: If it's a `requests` bug then might be worth posting an issue on the repo

Comment: Open session as a stream, set timeout to None and save stream chunks to a file as they come. It might be possible your network is slow or unstable. If it doesn't work it may be that the server is hanging your request(try with all of your browser's headers in order as well). I doubt the library has any issues

Comment: I tried all your suggestions above. I even enabled the Debug-Logger.  I dont think that the headers are the problem, because the exact same requests sometimes works just fine. Every 10th request or so is handled correctly.